# Adding object to ArrayList seems not working in my code(Java language)

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create ArrayList of objects and add new object to array with for loop.

Here is my code:

Basically I am trying to create grid from squares and I need to add object `Square` to ArrayList named `squaresInPlatform` that is shown below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Platform
{
    private int numberOfColumns;
    private int numberOfRows;
    private ArrayList<Square> squaresInPlatform;
    private int posX;
    private int posY;

    public Platform(int numOfColumns,int numOfRows)
    {
        this.squaresInPlatform = new ArrayList<Square>();
        this.numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns;
        this.numberOfRows = numberOfRows;
        this.posX = 50;
        this.posY = 60;
    }
    
    public void createColumn() {
        for(int column = 0; column < this.numberOfColumns; column++) {
            Square obj = new Square(this.posX, this.posY);
            this.squaresInPlatform.add(obj); 
            this.posX += 40;
            System.out.println("added" + " " + column + " " + "object");
        }
        
        for(Square i: this.squaresInPlatform ){
            i.drawSquare();
        }
    }
```

Square class:
In this class I am creating a Square from individual segments and then drawing the square or hiding it.
This class works perfectly.

```
public class Square
{
    private Segment upperSegment;
    private Segment rightSegment;
    private Segment downSegment;
    private Segment leftSegment;
    private int posX;
    private int posY;
    
    public Square(int posX, int posY)
    {
        this.posX = posX;
        this.posY = posY;
        this.upperSegment = new Segment(this.posX,this.posY,40,5);
        this.rightSegment = new Segment(this.posX+40,this.posY,5,40);
        this.downSegment = new Segment(this.posX,this.posY+40,45,5);
        this.leftSegment = new Segment(this.posX,this.posY,5,40);
    }
    
    public void drawSquare(){
        this.upperSegment.showSegment();
        this.rightSegment.showSegment();
        this.downSegment.showSegment();
        this.leftSegment.showSegment();
    }
    
    public void hideSquare(){
        this.upperSegment.hideSegment();
        this.rightSegment.hideSegment();
        this.downSegment.hideSegment();
        this.leftSegment.hideSegment(); 
    }
    
    public void changePositionOfSquare(int aPosX, int aPosY){
        this.posX = aPosX;
        this.posY = aPosY;
    }
    
    public int getPositionX(){
         return this.posX;
    }
    
    public int getPositionY(){
        return this.posY;
    }
}
```

Whole code works perfectly up until function in Platform class `createColumn`. When I run the function it is not throwing any error but also it is not adding any `Square` object to ArrayList named `squaresInPlatform`. I also created method where I am asking to show size of ArrayList `squaresInPlatform` after running the loop but it always showed size=0

Comment: I can't spot any glaring issues with the provided snippet. However, you don't show your `main` method and your `Square` class, so we can't be sure where the issue is. Please provide a [mre] of your problem. Also, how can you tell, that it is "_not adding any object to array_"?

Comment: @maloomeister I edited the question I hope you will more understand it now.

Comment: You still did not provide a [mre], since your `main` method and also `Segment` for example is missing. So I can't help you further. Is the for loop in `createCollumn()` run at all?

Comment: `Main` just create object `platform` and it calls function `createCollumn`. I am working with blueJ for learning purpose. And basically segment create one side of square and function `draw` in `segment` will draw the side of square to the canvas.